# Is there a 'correct' way to label test values in console?

Tags: javascript, debugging, console.log

I am writing a js app. I am trying to debug output of URLs that are dynamically generated.
If I log the following,

```
console.log('string: '+false); //  string: false 

console.log(false); // false

console.log("is external url: '+'http://something.com'.substr(0,7)=='http://'); //false
//expected: is external url: true

console.log('http://something.com'.substr(0,7)=='http://'); //true
```

I can easily write:

```
console.log('is external url: ');
console.log('http://something.com'.substr(0,7)=='http://');
```

but I am just trying to avoid having to write two lines for each condition I want to see.

Is it possible to write the label and the test in one line of console output?

TIA 
-Dylan

Comment: Assign the conditional to a variable, then log it like you do in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must debuggers [console.log](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#writing_to_the_console) allows you to use commas to sepreate multiple values

```
console.log('string: ', false); //  string: false
```

Another great way to organize data is to use groups.

```
console.group("iteration" + i);
console.log("current time: ", new Date());
console.groupEnd("iteration" + i);
```

And if you are trying to do a test, most debuggers have assertions built in

```
 console.assert(foobar < 100, "foobar is greater than 100");
```

Comment: BTW - console.log also allows the newline character: \n

Comment: Thank you. After reading this I searched 'using console.log correctly'. Lead me to: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#using_the_console_api

Comment: Which is the link I posted if you click console.log on my first line. ;)